# Opening PDF attachemnet

Tags: sql, vb.net

There is a pdf attachment in the gridview.I can open all other attachment except one(5).Each atachment is in each row of gridview.5th one, when i open below error message is coming

There was an error opening this document.The file is damaged and could not be repaired. How to solve this issue.

(When I open that PDF from its path(c:..)it is opening.)

Comment: Already changed the pdf file in the path.From the path ,I can open that specific pdf as other pdf.

Comment: It appears that the file is damaged and could not be repaired. That's the only thing anyone can solve by this question, as you've not provided any code

Comment: When I debug,no error is capturing and it is showing the File download dialogbox with open,save ,cancel as other pdf .But Once I click open, then only the error message is showing.

Comment: Please add the codes you are using to read the PDF.The fact that all other documents are opening except for one makes me think twice.If your code(which is not posted) is correct and working for all other PDFs , it should also work for he last one,right ?

Comment: If the PDF opens successfully from the disk then yes potentially your code is doing something wrong. But without seeing your code we can't help you. Also, are all the other attachments (which open successfully) PDFs, or some other file type?

Comment: Yes,All the other attachments of same file type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using  BinaryWrite Method as below.

```
   var data = getdataAndOtherThingsFromService();
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-length",      data.DocumentStream.Length.ToString());
     Response.BinaryWrite(data.DocumentStream);
     Response.End();
```